# React. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {slide})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день. Получаю ошибку рендера в следующей ситуации.
Я не очень понимаю что в этой ситуации должно быть массивом. Я итак беру список данных и в App.js рендерю весь список.

Самое интересное, что если я уберу `this.state.isOpen &&` из `const slide = this.state.isOpen && <div className="item">
            <h3 className="item__hero">{hero}</h3>
            <p className="item__text">{text}</p>
            <img className="item__picture" src={image}/>
        </div> ;`
то все заработает корректно..

привожу полный код моих компонентов:

Slide.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Slide extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: props.defaultOpen
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {hero, text, image} = this.props;

        const slide = this.state.isOpen && <div className="item">
            <h3 className="item__hero">{hero}</h3>
            <p className="item__text">{text}</p>
            <img className="item__picture" src={image}/>
        </div> ;

        return (
            {slide}

        )
    }
}

export default Slide;
```

SliderItemList.js

```
export default function SliderItemList({sliderItems}) {
    const sliderElements = sliderItems.map((item, i) =>
        <Slide key={i} {...item} defaultOpen={i === 0}/>
    )

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="slider__items">
                {sliderElements}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SliderItemList from './components/SliderItemList';
import Slider from './components/Slider';

import feed from './feed';

class App extends Component {


    count = feed.slider.length;

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="container">
                <button>Left</button>
                <button>Right</button>
                <p>{this.count}</p>

                <SliderItemList sliderItems={feed.slider}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

И собственно массив объектов с данными:

```
const feed = {
    "slider": [
        {
            "hero": "https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals",
            "text": "Animals are here.",
            "image": "https://placeimg.com/150/150/animals/sepia"
        },
        {
            "hero": "https://placeimg.com/640/480/people",
            "text": "People are here.",
            "image": "https://placeimg.com/150/150/people/sepia"
        },
        {
            "hero": "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech",
            "text": "Tech is here.",
            "image": "https://placeimg.com/150/150/tech/sepia"
        }
    ]
};

export default feed;
```

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {slide}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: "Самое интересное, что если я уберу this.state.isOpen && ....... то все заработает корректно..". Судя по этой фразе предположу что если this.state.isOpen === false, то компонента не знает что возвращать.

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин, нет. компонент не должен ничего возвращать, если условие не верно. тут вопрос в том, что я должен сделать массивом...

Comment: В случае если у вас this.state.isOpen === false, то компонента будет делать return ({ undefined })

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин если изменю на запись ` this.state.isOpen ? <div>...</div> : null; ` ничего не меняется, ошибка та же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@VladyslavTereshyn попробуйте переписать вашу компоненту Slide.js

```
render() {
    const {hero, text, image} = this.props;

    if (this.state.isOpen) {
        return (
             <div className="item">
                 <h3 className="item__hero">{hero}</h3>
                 <p className="item__text">{text}</p>
                 <img className="item__picture" src={image}/>
             </div>
        )
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: так работает, а почему тот способ не годился?

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn надо оборачивать в какой-нибудь тег:)

Comment: так был же обернут? или не так?

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn если у вас this.state.isOpen === false, то было бы return ({undefined}), и это не работало бы, а если бы вы сделали return (<div>{undefined}</div>), то все было бы ок:)